# Why do I get a injector error when importing ngMaterial?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using AngularJS and trying to use the angularJS material datepicker. I have been following the tutorial video at https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-material-containers-with-the-layout-api
However, I keep getting this error and dont know why?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=kg-App&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.9%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngMaterial%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.9%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngMaterial%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A76%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A408%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A439)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A26%253A182%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A332%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A180)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A364%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A8%253A7)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.6.9%252Fangular.min.js%253A42%253A180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A76%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A99%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A364%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A250)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)
```

The error happens when I inject the ngMaterial in my app.js

```
 angular.module('kg-App', ['ui.router','ngMaterial'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

  });
```

I followed the video and have all the scripts that I need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="kg-App">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>KG Strength</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/master/dist/angular-moment-picker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/html" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/newform.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/admin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/nextsession.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header-template></header-template>
    <image-template></image-template>
    <footer-template></footer-template>
    <ui-view autoscroll='true'></ui-view>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/html" src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/html" src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/html" src="node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/html" src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Please help

Comment: Why is the `type` for your script references `text/html`? I'm not saying it's not valid, I've just never seen javascript references with that type before.

Comment: Please paste your folder structure here

Answer (score 0):

- Move the jquery.js script reference before angular.js (important, because angular.js use it internally )
- in the App.js, add a dependance to ngMessages !

  angular.module('kg-App', ['ui.router','ngMaterial', **'ngMessages'**])

Also take a look to [enter link description here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started) (the video you looked seem outdated)